# how to resize UIScrollView to fit content of children UITextViews

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, xcode5, uitextview

I have a UIScrollView with a number of children UITextViews arranged vertically. I want the UIScrollView to resize to fit content. So my TextViews I do

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
    textView.frame = newFrame;
    [textView setNeedsLayout];
}
```

And for the scrollview I do

```
-(void)resizeScrollViewToFitContent
{
    CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;
    for (UIView *view in self.scrollView.subviews) {
        contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, view.frame);
    }
    self.scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size;
}
```

I call `[self resizeScrollViewToFitContent]` inside `viewDidAppear`. Any ideas why this setup is not working?

Comment: Are you able to upload a sample project to Github?

Comment: no. I am not permitted to upload the project to a public repo.

Comment: Just make a new sample project, 1 view controller with scrollview and also textviews + the code to resize the textview/scrollview that you have done.

Comment: Based on my troubleshooting, `resizeScrollViewToFitContent ` is not working. It's not adding up based on the size of its children. It increases arbitrarily.

Comment: I also notice that `self.scrollView.contentSize` is rejecting the assignment: Even if I try to assign some magic numbers to it, it rejects it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how is the arrangement of your textViews inside the scrollView. I assume that they are arranged vertically right next to each other. I have created a sample project with a scrollView and 3 textViews and it works well with the following code:-

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    CGFloat height = self.textView1.frame.size.height +self.textView2.frame.size.height +self.textView3.frame.size.height ;
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, height);
    self.scrollView.contentSize = size;
}
```

From my own project, the content Height of the scrollview is the combination of the height for all 3 textviews. It might be different in your project.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried that. The two subviews add up to 350. And even after assignment to the scrollView, the height of the scrollview is 520 (frame height). But the problem seems to be frame vs content size. The content size is correct when I check it. But when I check the size of the frame's height, it fails. And doing `[self.scrollView sizeToFit]` does not help.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? From my experience, the frame size for the scrollView is normally fixed on storyboard. I only adjust the content size of the scrollview when any subviews need to resize. You might want to check that from your storyboard. It is best if you are able to upload a sample project somewhere so that I can get the full picture.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing the union of the contentFrame and view.frame. Try the following:

```
-(void)resizeScrollViewToFitContent
{
    UIScrollView* scrollView;
    CGSize contentSize = CGSizeZero;
    for (UIView* subview in scrollView.subviews)
    {
        CGFloat subviewRight = CGRectGetMaxX(subview.frame);
        if (subviewRight > contentSize.width)
        {
            contentSize.width = subviewRight;
        }

        CGFloat subviewBottom = CGRectGetMaxY(subview.frame);
        if (subviewBottom > contentSize.height)
        {
            contentSize.height = subviewBottom;
        }
    }
    scrollView.contentSize = contentSize;
}
```

One small thing worth noting: a UIScrollView's scroll indicators are subviews of any UIScrollView. This has the potential to throw off the above code's accuracy, but I've found that it always works except in some very particular cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many subviews are in your scrollview per row then you'll want to do a little math to find the correct height.

For example, you might have a uiview with a uiimageview and uilabel, so you're subview count will be 3 times what it should be.

try

// csv = contentscrollview

```
NSLog(@"%d", [[csv subviews] count] / 3);
```